# Set text in flash file containing stuff in the html code

Tags: text, flash

I want to create a flash file containing some text given by HTML code. For example like this:

```
<object data="text.swf">
    <param name="FlashVars" value="text=The given text">
</object>
```

But i don't have such swf file. So how can i make an swf file like that? Is there any program for it? Or is there already an swf file for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*So how can i make an swf file like that? Is there any program for it?*

To create swf files you need software like Adobe Flash CS5, which isn't free. I found a list of open source alternatives for you but I don't know the quality of this software: [see here](http://www.flex888.com/152/about-30-open-source-flash-projects.html).

To pass variables from HTML to the flash file, this should work:

`<param name="FlashVars" value="example=test">` under the other `param` tags, and `flashvars="example=test"` as extra attribute in the `embed` tag.

The variable will then be globally accessible in the flash movie.

`trace(example)` -> output: test